# Display simple JSON string from URL in HTML

Tags: html, json

I've scoured stackoverflow and other forums for a solution to this all afternoon and I admit defeat.  Any help would be appreciated with this please:

I have a Google Drive spreadsheet that I've got to export data out as JSON via a third party URL.  The data looks like this...

```
{"columns":{"attendance":["Bob, Sue, Sam, Joe, "]},"rows":[{"attendance":"Bob, Sue, Sam, Joe, "}]}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting duplication from the Sheets export but I'm sure I can ignore that.  I just want to output the list of names once on an HTML page so I can use it with a digital signage solution that I've setup.  The names will change on a regular basis, hence the reason I'm feeding via a URL.  My best stab at a solution (and it's poor!) is:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://gsx2json.com/api?id=SHEET_URL_GOES_HERE">
</object>
```

I want to parse it though to strip out everything but the names. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exatcly ? HTML is not JSON capable, unless you just want it as a string, so I don't understand the purpose of your object tag

Comment: I tried with JavaScript and got nowhere so I tried to to scrape the data with an HTML object.  My knowledge with this is terrible.  I can thrash around in HTML and JavaScript a little but I can't get very far.

Comment: Ok no problem, as a guess you then just want to populate an HTML table with the "attendance" values ?

Comment: have you tried [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)?

Comment: That would be great, or even just output all the data as a string.

Comment: Then yea, as @Laassari say, just try AJAX, then you'll get your JSON and play with it as you wish. See this 
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) for understanding. You're going on the basics of JS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for both of your responses.  I got there and thought I'd post my solution in case it helps anyone else:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">

</head>

<script>

window.onload = loadDoc()

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     var jout = JSON.stringify(myObj.columns.attendance);

     var joutstrip2 = jout.substring(2, jout .length-4);
     document.getElementById("dataout").innerHTML = (joutstrip2)
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://gsx2json.com/api?id=GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID_GOES_HERE_&sheet=1", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

</script>

<div id="dataout"></div>

</body>
</html>
```